# Install Virtualbox 6 on Mac 10.14 Mojave failed with kernel install error

Tags: virtualbox, macos-mojave

Install Virtual box on mac OS +10.3 with security kernel can failed. After you have this message :

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

because you have to add editor Oracle in the list of security kext.

If you have chance, you can see the ask for authorisation in Preference -> "Security and Privacy".

But it was not my case. I want to share the solution, because it was a really pain for me:
Add Oracle editor in this authorization list.

> Restart your mac in Recovery mode (cmd + R)
>
> Then open a Terminal and enter : `spctl kext-consent add VB5E2TV963`
>
> Restart your mac.

`VB5E2TV963` is the code for oracle.

It's ok for me with Mojave and Virtual Box 6.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, this was the only thing that allowed me to install it!